# Rails redirection to custom action in devise subclassed sessions controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

my_devsie/sessions_controller.rb

```
class MyDevise::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    def dash_board  
    end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    protect_from_forgery with: :exception

    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
        sign_in_url = url_for(:action => 'dash_board', :controller => '/my_devise/sessions',       :only_path => false, :protocol => 'http')
        if request.referer == sign_in_url
            super
        else
            stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
        end
    end
end
```

routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "my_devise/registrations",
                                sessions: "my_devise/sessions" }
```

app structure

```
app  
---controller  
------my_devise  
---------sessoins_controller.rb
```

and the error is

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /users/sign_in
No route matches {:action=>"dash_board", :controller=>"my_devise/sessions"}
```

I would like to redirect to "dash_board" method in my_devise/session_controller for displaying appropriate dashboard view after successfull login, sign-up and profile update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The routes is not been found for the dash_board action. You must add a route for it. Try below if it works.

```
devise_scope :user do
    get "my_dashboard" =>"my_devise/sessions#dash_board"
end
```